# Invitees not getting the invitation mail for Outlook event

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Issue:While creating an event in the outlook default calendar, the invitees are not getting the event invitation mail in outlook and the events are not syncing in the outlook calendar.

I have attached the sample which we used to create event in outlook.

API : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Request body :

```
{
    "subject": "Test Event Creation 1",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Got event invitation mail?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-24T20:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-03-24T20:30:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "testuser@outlook.com",
                "name": "Test-user"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ]
}
```